# How to exit the program when a user enters a negative value - Java

Tags: java

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    System.out.print("How much can you afford for meals per day? Enter it now ");
    double mealAmount = input.nextDouble();
```

Comment: Just put that check (of if the number is negative, exit) immediately after you get the number, before you get the next number. Otherwise, how would the computer know that you want to exit immediately? You told it "get three numbers from the user, and then do some checks on them," so that's what it's going to do. Computers are very literal. :)

Answer (score 2):

This because your tests are performed **only after getting the 3 double values**. You should move the tests corresponding to each variable just after getting its value thanks to `input.nextDouble()`.

**Your code should rather be:**

```
System.out.print("How much can you afford for meals per day? Enter it now ");
double mealAmount = input.nextDouble();  

if (mealAmount <0)
    System.exit(0);
else if (mealAmount < 15.00 && mealAmount >=0)
    System.out.println("No meal for you. Tough luck.");
else if (mealAmount >= 15.00 && mealAmount < 30.00)
    System.out.println("You can afford bronze meals.");
else if (mealAmount >= 30.00 && mealAmount < 60.00)
    System.out.println("You can afford silver meals.");
else if (mealAmount >= 60.00)
    System.out.println("You can afford gold meals.");
...
```

**NB:** No need to explicitly call `System.exit(0)` simply use `return`.